# Passing data between components with ngFor not working on Angular14

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I am working on a personal project where I want to register every meal I eat along the day, and display them using charts.

I already know how to pass data between components using `Input()` between parent and child, but my problem here is slightly different. I provide the code and then explain what is my problem.

**today.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="loaded">
        <div *ngFor="let meal of mealList">
          <h1>{{ meal.name }}</h1>
          <app-chart
            [numCalories]="meal.calories"
            [numCarbs]="meal.carbs"
            [numFat]="meal.fat"
            [numProtein]="meal.protein"
          >
          </app-chart>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="!loaded" class="alert alert-info">
        Loading data...
      </div>
```

**today.component.ts**

```
export class TodayComponent implements OnInit {
  mealList: Meal[] = [];
  loaded: boolean = false;

  constructor(private mealService: MealService, private router: Router, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMeals();
  }
  
  getMeals() {
    this.mealService.getMeals().subscribe((meals) => {
      this.mealList = meals;
    });
    this.loaded = true;
  }   
 }
```

**chart.component.html**

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div style="display: block">
      <div>
        <canvas baseChart [data]="doughnutChartData" [type]="doughnutChartType">
        </canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**chart.component.ts**

```
export class ChartComponent {
  @Input() numCalories!: number;
  @Input() numFat!: number;
  @Input() numCarbs!: number;
  @Input() numProtein!: number;

  constructor() {}

  public doughnutChartLabels: string[] = [
    'Calories',
    'Proteins',
    'Carbs',
    'Fat',
  ];
  public doughnutChartData: ChartData<'doughnut'> = {
    labels: this.doughnutChartLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [
          this.numCalories,
          this.numFat,
          this.numCarbs,
          this.numProtein,
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
  public doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';
}
```

I know the data is loading correctly because, in the HTML layout of **today's** component, where I use `{{ meal.name }}`, I am referring to the time when you eat, for example dinner, lunch, and it loads fine, so my problem is passing the other data to the **chart** component.

Since I am assigning the data I want to pass with an NgFor, I do not have that variable in the parent component, and that is how it is made in every example I have seen, and it seems I need to do something else, but I do not really know what to do.

Comment: Why not just pass in a single Input of type `Meal` instead of individual properties?

Comment: Because I thought it would be easier to assign every field in the chart dataset like that, but if you could provide an example of how you would do that, I would really appreciate @penleychan

Comment: I am assuming you are trying to get other properties from `Meal`. All you do is use `@Input() meal: Meal;` on your chart component and access them like `this.meal.name`, `this.meal.carbs` etc etc.

Comment: I am doing what you are saying. When I assign the values to the dataset, it gives an error in console like this: "cannot read properties of undefined", but I am also printing the value of this.meal and I am getting all the data correctly on th econsole

Comment: this.loaded = true; should be inside the subscribe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to set `doughnutChartData` within `ngOnInit`.

[Keep in mind that a directive's data-bound input properties are not set until after construction.](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#initializing-a-component-or-directive)

```js
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() numCalories!: number;
  @Input() numFat!: number;
  @Input() numCarbs!: number;
  @Input() numProtein!: number;

  public doughnutChartData: ChartData<'doughnut'> = null;
  public doughnutChartLabels: string[] = [
    'Calories',
    'Proteins',
    'Carbs',
    'Fat',
  ];
  public doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.doughnutChartData = {
      labels: this.doughnutChartLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [
            this.numCalories,
            this.numFat,
            this.numCarbs,
            this.numProtein,
          ],
        },
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

or through a single Input of type Meal, as advised by @penleychan

```js
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() meal!: Meal;

  public doughnutChartData: ChartData<'doughnut'> = null;
  public doughnutChartLabels: string[] = [
    'Calories',
    'Proteins',
    'Carbs',
    'Fat',
  ];
  public doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.doughnutChartData = {
      labels: this.doughnutChartLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [
            this.meal.numCalories,
            this.meal.numFat,
            this.meal.numCarbs,
            this.meal.numProtein,
          ],
        },
      ],
    }
  }
}
```